# Grails 3.2.2 Select Options from Domain Constraints

Tags: select, grails, groovy

Is it possible to fill the options of a `<select>` with the availables options in a domain's `constraints`

```
static constraints = {
    variable(inList: ["value1", "value2", "value3"])
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the list by:

```
YourClass.getConstrainedProperties().yourProperty.inList
```

You can use this in a `g:each` loop to create your select options or use the `g:select` tag as such: `<g:select from="${YourClass.getConstrainedProperties().yourProperty.inList}" />`

Comment: Thanks @Joshua Moore for adding the g:select tag as an alternative solution instead of use g:each. Definitely the better way and the way to go!